# Using GMM to estimate ordered probit

Tags: stata, gmm

I'm following this article: https://blog.stata.com/2016/09/13/an-ordered-probit-inverse-probability-weighted-ipw-estimator/
In the "Using gmm to solve the multistep estimation problem" section, the author uses fairly complicated moments to replicate Stata oprobit command results. I wonder why he can't just use the standard $E[x'(y_i-\Phi(x\beta))]=0$ moments?
But when I try to use these moments in Stata, I got the error: "could not calculate numerical derivatives -- flat or discontinuous region encountered"

Using the data provided in the article, this is my code:

gmm (eq1: (t==1) - normal({alp}-{xb:x1 x2 _cons}) + normal(-{xb:})) (eq2: (t==2) - 1 + normal({alp}-{xb:})) , instruments(eq1: x1 x2) instruments(eq2: x1 x2) winitial(identity) onestep

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.